# Oracle SQL Developer through socks proxy

Tags: java, proxy

I want to connect with Oracle SQL Developer via a socks proxy (through ssh session: `ssh -D 8182 myserver`). 
I found [this link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2208308?tstart=0), but it did not work for me.

Can anyone help me here?

I also wrote a small `Java` class which connects to a database which is only available via proxy and this worked.